# Generating a .java outof .dll with jni4net

Tags: java, c#, dll, java-native-interface, jni4net

I have my c# class library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Keyence.IV.Sdk;
using System.Reflection;
namespace JavaKameraSchnittstelle
{

public class KeyenceKameraSchnittstellen
{   
    private IVisionSensor[] sensor;
    private VisionSensorStore store;
    private List<byte[]> images;
    private DateTime lastUpdate;
    private bool[] areConnected;


    public KeyenceKameraSchnittstellen()
    {
    ...
    }

    //Listner
    public void ImageAcquired(object sender, ImageAcquiredEventArgs e)
    {
    ...
    }

    public void startTickTack()
    {
    ...
    }

    private void setImageAquiredListener()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void readIniDatei()
    {
       ...
    }

    private void init()
    {
        ...
    }

    private System.Net.IPAddress getLocalIp()
    {
        ...
    }

    public IVisionSensor[] getVisionSensoren()
    {
        ...
    }

    public List<byte[]> getImages()
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool[] getAreConnected()
    {
       ...
    }
}
}
```

Its based on a `Keyence.IV.Sdk.dll`. I added this .dll as Assembly via Visual Studio. The compiler is friendly and shows no erros. (In a Windows-Applikation the code works fine.)

Now i want to make a Bridge with

> JNI4Net (proxygen.exe -...\dll ....)
>   [image]

Now i want to execute the build.cmd, but I'm getting this error:

```
Z:\bwulf\GeneratedSchnittstelle>build.cmd
compile classes
JavaKameraSchnittstelle.j4n.jar
JavaKameraSchnittstelle.j4n.dll clr\javakameraschnittstelle\KeyenceKameraSchnittstellen.generated.cs(58,165): error CS0400: Der Typ- oder Namespacename
        'Keyence' konnte im globalen Namespace nicht gefunden werden. (Fehlt ein Assemblyverweis?) clr\javakameraschnittstelle\KeyenceKameraSchnittstellen.generated.cs(79,85): error CS0400: Der Typ- oder Namespacename
        'Keyence' konnte im globalen Namespace nicht gefunden werden. (Fehlt ein Assemblyverweis?) clr\javakameraschnittstelle\KeyenceKameraSchnittstellen.generated.cs(79,125): error CS0400: Der Typ- oder Namespacename
        'Keyence' konnte im globalen Namespace nicht gefunden werden. (Fehlt ein Assemblyverweis?) clr\javakameraschnittstelle\KeyenceKameraSchnittstellen.generated.cs(79,13): error CS0012: Der Typ
        'Keyence.IV.Sdk.IVisionSensor' ist in einer nicht referenzierten Assembly definiert. Fügen Sie einen Verweis auf        die Assembly 'Keyence.IV.Sdk, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' hinzu. z:\bwulf\KameraSchnittstelle\JavaKameraSchnittstelle.dll: (Position des Symbols für den vorherigen Fehler)
```

I'm not familiar with c#. I found something with `Assembly.LoadFile()...` but could not really do anything with it.

Where is the mistake and why i'm getting this error :

> 'Keyence' namespace not found.

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the contents of your build.cmd file.

Assuming your `build.cmd` is equivalent to [this](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/blob/master/content/samples/helloWorldFromCLR/build.cmd)

> Csc.exe /nologo /warn:0 /reference:....\lib\jni4net.n-0.8.9.0.dll /out:work/helloWorldFromCLR.exe /target:exe Program.cs

It looks like a way to compile your C# program.

The error CS0400 [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0400)

> The type or namespace name 'identifier' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Essentially, your `build.cmd` is not finding the other assembly - `Keyence.IV.Sdk.dll`

You can add it via the `/reference:` option so that the compiler `Csc.exe` can find the assembly. Edit your `build.cmd` file and add the additional `/reference:` sections for the additional assemblies you add in your Visual Studio project reference.

You can look at the full compiler options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option)

Comment: Thank you. It worked after i added the  ´/reference "path"´.